# cannot find package "google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go"

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

The page [Protocol Buffer Basics: Go](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/gotutorial) says 2 things:
1) Download the package and follow instructions in README
2) Run go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go
Following the [Download Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/downloads) points to the [release page](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/latest) which has tar and zip files for lots of languages (C++, C#, ...) but not Go. The file protobuf-all-3.12.3.tar.gz has many languages, but not Go. The README says for Go, head off to [Go support for Protocol Buffers](https://github.com/golang/protobuf) which says that it has been superseded by [module google.golang.org/protobuf](https://pkg.go.dev/mod/google.golang.org/protobuf). There aren't any installation instructions by the time I've got there, just more general stuff pointing to even more pages. So I tried step (2)

```
go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go
```

and got

```
can't load package: package google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go: cannot find package "google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go" in any of ...
```

I have 9 tabs open on my browser pointing to various Golang Protocol Buffer pages, and I still haven't managed to get going. I've downloaded protoc and got it working ok for Java and Python, but installing Go has got me beat so far. Is there a page that tells me what to do, in a simple way? Once upon a time using the Github repository it was easy, but that was long ago...
Thanks, Jan

Answer (score 15):

Running

```
go get -u google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go
```

first before go install seems to have solved it.

Comment: it is safer to run the function without the parameter -u, as running "go get -u ..." could have unwanted results, especially for people like me who have recently started using golang and its toolchain. When you use the -u option with the `go get` command it will look to apply minimal version selection to upgrade transitive dependencies to their latest versions as well.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have a `go.mod`:

```
go mod init github.com/org/repo
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Download `protoc` binary for required OS: [github.com => protobuf => releases](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases)
2. Add `protoc` to `$PATH`
3. Install `protoc-gen-go` to `$GOBIN`:

```
user ~ % go install github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
go: finding github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go latest
go: downloading google.golang.org/protobuf v1.23.0
go: extracting google.golang.org/protobuf v1.23.0
go: finding google.golang.org/protobuf v1.23.0
```

**Note:** to specific version add `@v` + `version`

**Note:** `Go` Automatically install `protoc-gen-go` binary to `$GOBIN`, if `$GOBIN` did not set, it's equals `$GOPATH/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing the binary with the below command:

```
go install github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
```

If you are looking for a specific version, try:

```
go install github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go@v1.3
```

> Note: Make sure you set the GOBIN before you run the above commands

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but my understanding is that the github package is deprecated: "It has been superseded by the google.golang.org/protobuf module" on the https://github.com/golang/protobuf page

Answer (score 1):

see this.
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated

you need go version 1.16 or higher. check that.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in @jeremyko's comment, you will need Go 1.16 or higher. I personally installed Go from the APT repository, which often has outdated packages. It installed 1.13, so I had problems with installing OpenSnitch.

You can download the latest version from [here](https://golang.org/dl/).